# -[Countries retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6829280

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I am using storyboard with tab bar application. In one of tab I made a tableView. Data populates ok. There's the problem when I am trying to navigate to another UITableViewController in the same tab.

Countries.h (class bidden with storyboard)

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *items;
@property(nonatomic,retain)Country *country;
@property(nonatomic)int continentID;
```

Method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.continent=[self.items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    Countries *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theCountries"];
detailViewController.continentID=self.continent.continentID;
detailViewController.title=self.continent.continentName;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 [detailViewController release];
}
```

While navigating I am getting -[Countries retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6829280 . Doesn't self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theCountries" allocates the instance? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overreleasing your `detailViewController` object.

Btw, the static analyzer would have caught that error.

Comment: I've commented [detailsViewController release] and got Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Continents setContinent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b67f80'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x159a022 0x172bcd6 0x159bcbd 0x1500ed0 0x1500cb2 0x387c 0x16c5c5 0x16c7fa 0xa0185d 0x156e936 0x156e3d7 0x14d1790 0x14d0d84 0x14d0c9b 0x14837d8 0x148388a 0xdb626 0x2342 0x22b5)
terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Sounds like you did not implement `-setContinent:` very much. Btw, only methods whose names start with "new", "init" or "copy" should (and in apples frameworks do) return retained objects.